# HorizontalScrollView with EditText jumps to right

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout

I have some problem with `HorizontalScrollView` and `EditTexts` inside. When I start typing `HorizontalScrollView` jumps to right and editting `EditText` dissapears although focus doesn't lose. But if I remove `editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` all works fine. I read about overriding `scrollTo()` but I want to know why it's happened and remove the cause rather than the consequences.

Here is sample code:

**R.layout.activity_main:**

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRowSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private LinearLayout llRowSearch;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    llRowSearch = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llRowSearch);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(500,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
                | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        llRowSearch.addView(editText);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputType is the culprit, when we combine it with the gravity in the HorizontalScrollView.

Add android:digits="0123456789." to your EditText and it will not jump.